# d3 is not defined in unit testing jest

Tags: d3.js, jestjs, gulp-npm-test

error showing d3 is not defined when run test command "npm test".
[image]

Below image is my test script
[image]

Pie chart code is below image

[image: e]

Comment: How did you add D3js to your project? are you importing D3 to the script you are testing?

Comment: Yes. I added D3 in the script.

Comment: from the images, I think you need to require `d3` library just like you did with `chatbot-pie` library or maybe you can include it using your testing lib as a dependency, the error says that its not included in the testing function scope.

Comment: please give me an example to include lib and where to add.